# How do you setup and execute a MavenExecutionRequest with Maven Core v4.0.0?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, guice, plexus

I want to build a Maven project using the [Maven Core](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.1/maven-core/) (version [4.0.0-alpha-5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-core/4.0.0-alpha-5)) library. All I want right now is a working proof-of-concept to run the `install` phase. However, I have not been able to create a working example and I cannot find a single tutorial or demonstration on the internet.

My main method is quite straightforward, it shouldn't require explanation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new CompleteMavenModule());

    Maven maven = injector.getInstance(Maven.class);
    MavenExecutionRequestPopulator populator = injector.getInstance(MavenExecutionRequestPopulator.class);

    DefaultMavenExecutionRequest request = new DefaultMavenExecutionRequest();
    request.setPom(new File("C:\\Users\\lc70844\\eclipse-workspace\\TestProject\\pom.xml"));
    request.setGoals(Arrays.asList("install"));

    populator.populateDefaults(request);

    MavenExecutionResult result = maven.execute(request);
    if (result.hasExceptions())
        result.getExceptions().stream().forEach(Throwable::printStackTrace);
}
```

When I run this, I get the following exception:

```
org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.eclipse.aether.repository.WorkspaceReader
  roleHint: reactor
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:228)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at com.nhbb.test.MavenTest.main(MavenTest.java:43)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LocatedBeans$Itr.next(LocatedBeans.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 5 more
```

Going back to my main method, you'll notice the `Guice.createInjector(new CompleteMavenModule())`. The `CompleteMavenModule` class is a [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) module I setup to provide me with a [`DefaultMaven`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/4-LATEST/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/DefaultMaven.html) instance:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven;
import org.apache.maven.Maven;
import org.apache.maven.WorkspaceReaderModule;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.ArtifactFactory;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.manager.ArtifactHandlerManager;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.manager.DefaultArtifactHandlerManager;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.DefaultRepositoryLayout;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.DefaultMetadataReader;
import org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.MetadataReader;
import org.apache.maven.classrealm.ClassRealmManager;
import org.apache.maven.classrealm.ClassRealmManagerDelegate;
import org.apache.maven.classrealm.DefaultClassRealmManager;
import org.apache.maven.eventspy.EventSpy;
import org.apache.maven.execution.BuildResumptionAnalyzer;
import org.apache.maven.execution.BuildResumptionDataRepository;
import org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultBuildResumptionAnalyzer;
import org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultBuildResumptionDataRepository;
import org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MojoExecutionListener;
import org.apache.maven.execution.ProjectExecutionListener;
import org.apache.maven.execution.scope.internal.MojoExecutionScopeCoreModule;
import org.apache.maven.extension.internal.CoreExports;
import org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.graph.GraphBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.internal.impl.EventSpyImpl;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleMappingDelegate;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MojoExecutionConfigurator;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultProjectArtifactFactory;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.ExecutionEventCatapult;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.ProjectArtifactFactory;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.Builder;
import org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProcessor;
import org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelSourceTransformer;
import org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelProcessor;
import org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelSourceTransformer;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.DefaultModelReader;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.ModelReader;
import org.apache.maven.model.locator.DefaultModelLocator;
import org.apache.maven.model.locator.ModelLocator;
import org.apache.maven.model.superpom.DefaultSuperPomProvider;
import org.apache.maven.model.superpom.SuperPomProvider;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.BuildPluginManager;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultExtensionRealmCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginArtifactsCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginDescriptorCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginRealmCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.ExtensionRealmCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.LegacySupport;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginPrerequisitesChecker;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojosExecutionStrategy;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginArtifactsCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginDescriptorCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginRealmCache;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultLegacySupport;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.MavenPluginInternalModule;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.MavenPluginJavaPrerequisiteChecker;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.MavenPluginMavenPrerequisiteChecker;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.PluginDependenciesResolver;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.PluginPrefixResolver;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver;
import org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper;
import org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver;
import org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectRealmCache;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingHelper;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectDependenciesResolver;
import org.apache.maven.project.ProjectRealmCache;
import org.apache.maven.project.RepositorySessionDecorator;
import org.apache.maven.project.artifact.DefaultProjectArtifactsCache;
import org.apache.maven.project.artifact.ProjectArtifactsCache;
import org.apache.maven.project.collector.DefaultProjectsSelector;
import org.apache.maven.project.collector.ProjectsSelector;
import org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem;
import org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenResolverModule;
import org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem;
import org.apache.maven.rtinfo.RuntimeInformation;
import org.apache.maven.rtinfo.internal.DefaultRuntimeInformation;
import org.apache.maven.session.scope.internal.SessionScopeModule;
import org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.DefaultSettingsDecrypter;
import org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.SettingsDecrypter;
import org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer;
import org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer;
import org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.repository.WorkspaceReader;
import org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.RepositoryConnectorFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.TransporterFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.file.FileTransporterFactory;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.ChecksumExtractor;
import org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporterFactory;
import org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.DefaultPlexusCipher;
import org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher;
import org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcher;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;
import com.google.inject.util.Providers;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CompleteMavenModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenResolverModule does not provide
        // bindings for all the necessary dependencies
        install(new MavenResolverModule());
        install(new SessionScopeModule());
        install(new MojoExecutionScopeCoreModule());
        install(new MavenPluginInternalModule());
        install(new WorkspaceReaderModule());

        // make module "complete" by binding things not bound by MavenResolverModule
        bind(Maven.class).to(DefaultMaven.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(EventSpy.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("impl")).to(EventSpyImpl.class);
        bind(Builder.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("multithreaded")).to(MultiThreadedBuilder.class);
        bind(MojosExecutionStrategy.class).to(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ArtifactRepositoryLayout.class).to(DefaultRepositoryLayout.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ArtifactHandlerManager.class).to(DefaultArtifactHandlerManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(BuildResumptionAnalyzer.class).to(DefaultBuildResumptionAnalyzer.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(BuildResumptionDataRepository.class).to(DefaultBuildResumptionDataRepository.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(GraphBuilder.class).annotatedWith(Names.named(GraphBuilder.HINT)).to(DefaultGraphBuilder.class)
                .in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ExecutionEventCatapult.class).to(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(LifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.class).to(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.class)
                .in(Singleton.class);
        bind(LifecycleMappingDelegate.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("default"))
                .to(DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(MojoExecutionConfigurator.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("default"))
                .to(DefaultMojoExecutionConfigurator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(LifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.class).to(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ProjectArtifactFactory.class).to(DefaultProjectArtifactFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ArtifactFactory.class).to(DefaultArtifactFactory.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ModelLocator.class).to(DefaultModelLocator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ModelReader.class).to(DefaultModelReader.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ModelProcessor.class).to(DefaultModelProcessor.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(SuperPomProvider.class).to(DefaultSuperPomProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ModelSourceTransformer.class).to(DefaultModelSourceTransformer.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(BuildPluginManager.class).to(DefaultBuildPluginManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(LegacySupport.class).to(DefaultLegacySupport.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(MavenPluginManager.class).to(DefaultMavenPluginManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(MavenPluginPrerequisitesChecker.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("java"))
                .to(MavenPluginJavaPrerequisiteChecker.class);
        bind(MavenPluginPrerequisitesChecker.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("maven"))
                .to(MavenPluginMavenPrerequisiteChecker.class);
        bind(ClassRealmManager.class).to(DefaultClassRealmManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ExtensionRealmCache.class).to(DefaultExtensionRealmCache.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PluginArtifactsCache.class).to(DefaultPluginArtifactsCache.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PluginDescriptorCache.class).to(DefaultPluginDescriptorCache.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PluginRealmCache.class).to(DefaultPluginRealmCache.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PluginDependenciesResolver.class).to(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PluginPrefixResolver.class).to(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(MetadataReader.class).to(DefaultMetadataReader.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PluginVersionResolver.class).to(DefaultPluginVersionResolver.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ProjectBuilder.class).to(DefaultProjectBuilder.class);
        bind(ProjectBuildingHelper.class).to(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ProjectDependenciesResolver.class).to(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.class);
        bind(ProjectRealmCache.class).to(DefaultProjectRealmCache.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ProjectArtifactsCache.class).to(DefaultProjectArtifactsCache.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ProjectsSelector.class).to(DefaultProjectsSelector.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(RepositorySystem.class).to(LegacyRepositorySystem.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(RuntimeInformation.class).to(DefaultRuntimeInformation.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(SettingsDecrypter.class).to(DefaultSettingsDecrypter.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(PlexusContainer.class).to(DefaultPlexusContainer.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(WorkspaceReader.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ide")).toProvider(Providers.of(null))
                .in(Singleton.class);
        bind(SecDispatcher.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("maven"))
                .toInstance(new DefaultSecDispatcher(new DefaultPlexusCipher()));
        bind(MavenExecutionRequestPopulator.class).to(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(CoreExports.class).toInstance(new CoreExports(null, Collections.emptySet(), Collections.emptySet()));

        bind(RepositoryConnectorFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("basic"))
                .to(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.class);
        bind(TransporterFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("file")).to(FileTransporterFactory.class);
        bind(TransporterFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("http")).to(HttpTransporterFactory.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    List<RepositorySessionDecorator> getRepositorySessionDecorators() {
        // No implementations exist for
        // org.apache.maven.project.RepositorySessionDecorator
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    List<ClassRealmManagerDelegate> getClassRealmManagerDelegates() {
        // No implementations exist for
        // org.apache.maven.classrealm.ClassRealmManagerDelegate
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    List<MavenPluginPrerequisitesChecker> getMavenPluginPrerequisitesCheckers(
            @Named("java") MavenPluginPrerequisitesChecker java,
            @Named("maven") MavenPluginPrerequisitesChecker maven) {
        return Arrays.asList(java, maven);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    List<MojoExecutionListener> getMojoExecutionListeners(MojoExecutionListener listener) {
        return Arrays.asList(listener);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Map<String, MojoExecutionConfigurator> provideMojoExecutionConfigurators(
            @Named("default") MojoExecutionConfigurator defaultConfigurator) {
        return Stream.of(defaultConfigurator).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> "default", v -> v));
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Map<String, LifecycleMappingDelegate> provideLifecycleMappingDelegates(
            @Named("default") LifecycleMappingDelegate defaultDelegate) {
        return Stream.of(defaultDelegate).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> "default", v -> v));
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Map<String, ArtifactHandler> provideArtifactHandlers() {
        // No implementations exist for CompleteResolverModule.provideArtifactHandlers()
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Map<String, ArtifactRepositoryLayout> provideRepositoryLayouts(ArtifactRepositoryLayout defaultLayout) {
        return Stream.of(defaultLayout).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> "default", v -> v));
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    List<ProjectExecutionListener> provideProjectExecutionListeners() {
        // No listeners
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Map<String, Builder> provideLifecycleBuilders(@Named("multithreaded") Builder multi) {
        return Stream.of(multi).collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> "multithreaded", v -> v));
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    List<EventSpy> provideEventSpies(@Named("impl") EventSpy impl) {
        return Arrays.asList(impl);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Map<String, ChecksumExtractor> provideChecksumExtractors() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Set<RepositoryConnectorFactory> provideRepositoryConnectorFactories(
            @Named("basic") RepositoryConnectorFactory basic) {
        Set<RepositoryConnectorFactory> factories = new HashSet<>();
        factories.add(basic);
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(factories);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Set<TransporterFactory> provideTransporterFactories(@Named("file") TransporterFactory file,
            @Named("http") TransporterFactory http) {
        Set<TransporterFactory> factories = new HashSet<>();
        factories.add(file);
        factories.add(http);
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(factories);
    }

}
```

Right off the bat, I know that I am not doing this correctly. You'll notice these two lines:

```
install(new MavenPluginInternalModule());
install(new WorkspaceReaderModule());
```

I had to create these modules to setup bindings for [`ReadOnlyPluginParametersValidator`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/internal/ReadOnlyPluginParametersValidator.java), [`DefaultMavenPluginValidator`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/internal/DefaultMavenPluginValidator.java), and [`ReactorReader`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/ReactorReader.java), which are all package-private classes (the binding for ReactorReader was my attempt at addressing the error above). If these classes are private, it leads me to believe that some Maven class is supposed to setup these bindings for me. Judging by the fact that I have to create the bindings myself, I suspect that I am taking an improper approach to the dependency injection.

I noticed that Maven does not use Guice directly, but is working with the [`PlexusContainer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-container-default/latest/org/codehaus/plexus/PlexusContainer.html) interface in conjunction with [Plexus Classworlds](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-classworlds/) and [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) for dependency injection. I do not have a solid understanding of what these "Plexus" libraries are or how work, and I believe this is the root of my problem. Again, I cannot find documentation, examples, or demonstrations on how to use these libraries with Maven.

The exception I pasted above originated from [this line](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/DefaultMaven.java#L246) in the DefaultMaven class:

```
try {
    WorkspaceReader reactorReader = container.lookup(WorkspaceReader.class, ReactorReader.HINT);
    repoSession.setWorkspaceReader(reactorReader);
} catch (ComponentLookupException e) {
    return addExceptionToResult(result, e);
}
```

In this snippet, `container` is a PlexusContainer instance, not a Guice injector. I am quite convinced at this point that I need to be setting up my dependency injection with this "Plexus" library rather than Guice, but how? There is nothing I can find explaining how to do this.

---

**EDIT**: Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-maven-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-connector-basic</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-spi</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resolver-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `I want to build a Maven project using the ` why not simply by using the command line? via `mvn clean package` or alike? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise the purpose of my application is to deploy a Maven artifact and all of its dependencies to an internal company server. I need to 1) collect project info (group id, artifact id, version), 2) build the project, and 3) download and list dependencies (including transitive). The program needs the file paths to all the dependencies, as well as the project's jar (`project.build.directory` + `project.build.finalName`). Currently it uses Maven Invoker and parses the log output, but spinning up a new process to run Maven for each deployment is inefficient and the log output can vary.

Comment: That can simply being done via Maven itself via `mvn deploy`?

Comment: @khmarbaise is `mvn deploy` capable of deploying to a remote file system via SMB? Our internal company server is not a Maven repository, but rather a file server. There is also very particular logic in place to transfer files in a manner compatible with our VPN. Would I have to create my own mojo to do this? Lastly, I am still concerned about the inefficiency of spinning up a new process for each application that is deployed. If I must take a CLI approach, is there a way to keep the process alive and issue multiple different commands to it at any given time?

Comment: Using a file sever (SMB) for a maven repository is simply the wrong way use a repository manager... much easier to handle and is supported out of the box of Maven.. even if needed I would suggest not to use Maven 4.0.0-alpha.. use Maven 3.9.1 as foundation.. also it would be easier to simply build your app and use the content of the local cash ($HOME/.m2/repository) ... or define that location via command line `-Dmaven.local.repo=..` and `I am still concerned about the inefficiency of spinning up a new process` exactly that is the reason doing things the wrong way...

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for taking the time to work with me on this. Our programmers use the Maven CLI for *development* and we use a proper Nexus repository manager for our development builds and dependencies. The SMB server is a pre-existing file server which hosts our **completed applications** and dependencies as compiled jars (not fat jars), and distributes them to end-users. _We are **not** using the SMB server as a repository manager_. The goal is to decouple the completed projects from the Maven ecosystem so a *separate service* can distribute them to internal users from the SMB server.

Comment: My current approach uses Maven Invoker to run `mvn dependency:list -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true -DincludeScope=compile` and `mvn package`. It does not always work because I have to parse the raw output from these commands, which varies depending on the context. I am looking for a more reliable, consistent, and efficient approach. Can it be done with the CLI?